# issue while Setting Up PostgreSQL with rubyv2.5.9 on railsv5.0.7.2 on ubuntu18.04 virtual machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
kundan@DESKTOP-8FLVF57:/mnt/c$ rails new testapp -d postgresql 
   exist
   identical  README.md
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  config.ru
   identical  .gitignore
   identical  Gemfile
       exist  app
   identical  app/assets/config/manifest.js
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
   identical  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
   identical  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  app/jobs/application_job.rb
   identical  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
   identical  app/models/application_record.rb
   identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
    ......`enter code here`
    ......
```

/home/kundan/.rbenv/versions/2.5.9/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1243:in
`chmod': Operation not permitted @ apply2files
/mnt/c/testapp/bin
(Errno::EPERM)

Comment: Your going to need to add some context.

Comment: It looks file-system permission error.  The output of "ls -la /mnt/c /mnt/c/testapp" could be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.